# Ошибка NuGet пакетов при публикации

Tags: c#, nuget, c#-7.0, публикация-приложений

Всем здравствуйте!

Я уже 2 недели пытаюсь решить проблему.

Один раз, когда я пытался опубликовать проект, мне выдало ошибку (точно не помню, что-то в этом роде):

> не удалось получить индекс источника https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/index.json

Когда я выключал **nuget.org** в "*Диспетчере пакетов NuGet*", мне выдавало ошибку, что не хватает определенных библиотек (у меня включен источник "*Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages*").
Была даже ошибка, что не получается создать защищенный канал SSL / TLS. В данный момент у меня выписывает такое сообщение:

> Не удалось получить сведения о подписи репозитория для источника https://api.nuget.org/v3-index/repository-signatures/5.0.0/index.json.

Я обшарил уже весь интернет, и всегда выдает разные ошибки. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Switch on TLS1.2 support by:

reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v DisabledByDefault /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f /reg:64
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:32
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f /reg:64

Comment: Это сайт на русском, и отвечать здесь тоже надо на русском. Переведите, пожалуйста, ответ и отформатируйте его нормально.